# How to find an appropriate SELinux type to prevent "permission denied"

Tags: permissions, selinux, docker

## Objective

Find out a solution to avoid the permission denied due to SELinux.

### Background

Deployed a docker container which mounts the host file /var/run/docker but cannot access it within the container due to "Permission denied".

```
$ ls -Z /var/run/docker.sock
srw-rw----. root root system_u:object_r:container_var_run_t:s0 /var/run/docker.sock

$  sudo semanage fcontext -l | grep '/var/run/docker'
/var/run/docker\.sock                              socket             system_u:object_r:container_var_run_t:s0
```

The SELinux log shows below.

```
$ sudo cat /var/log/audit/audit.log | grep sock
type=AVC msg=audit(1516519533.557:1465348): avc:  denied  { connectto } for  pid=54437 comm="python" path="/run/docker.sock" scontext=system_u:system_r:svirt_lxc_net_t:s0:c556,c641 tcontext=system_u:system_r:container_runtime_t:s0 tclass=unix_stream_socket
type=AVC msg=audit(1516519533.966:1465349): avc:  denied  { connectto } for  pid=54440 comm="python" path="/run/docker.sock" scontext=system_u:system_r:svirt_lxc_net_t:s0:c556,c641 tcontext=system_u:system_r:container_runtime_t:s0 tclass=unix_stream_socket
```

Process IDs which is causing the permission denied.

```
root      53831  0.0  0.0 216508  1932 ?        Sl   18:24   0:00      \_ /usr/bin/docker-containerd-shim-current 28b7eb84ebfccd297ea18352b38b765f1f3ede5e03fb9f29b3218b7355110b7e /var/run/docker/libcontainerd/28b7eb84ebfccd297ea18352b38b765f1f3ede5e03fb9f29b3218b7355110
1001      53846  0.0  0.0   2668   720 ?        Ssl  18:24   0:00      |   \_ /pod
root      54329  0.0  0.0 280636  1932 ?        Sl   18:24   0:00      \_ /usr/bin/docker-containerd-shim-current 149bb5c7d37b4335ade587d7a1b38331b48ffe7ae83c865fd4afc2dbc2fccc4f /var/run/docker/libcontainerd/149bb5c7d37b4335ade587d7a1b38331b48ffe7ae83c865fd4afc2dbc2fcc
root      54345  0.1  0.1  95800 19040 ?        Ss   18:24   0:03          \_ /opt/datadog-agent/embedded/bin/python /opt/datadog-agent/bin/supervisord -n -c /etc/dd-agent/supervisor.conf
root      54435  0.0  0.0 275920  5732 ?        Sl   18:24   0:01              \_ /opt/datadog-agent/bin/trace-agent
root      54436  0.2  0.2 173424 40456 ?        S    18:24   0:07              \_ /opt/datadog-agent/embedded/bin/python /opt/datadog-agent/agent/ddagent.py
root      54437  0.1  0.2 219256 37668 ?        Sl   18:24   0:05              \_ /opt/datadog-agent/embedded/bin/python /opt/datadog-agent/agent/dogstatsd.py --use-local-forwarder
root      54440  1.4  0.3 320204 57180 ?        S    18:24   0:50              \_ /opt/datadog-agent/embedded/bin/python /opt/datadog-agent/agent/agent.py foreground --use-local-forwarder
```

The label of the denied process.

```
$ ps -Z -P 54440
LABEL                              PID PSR TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
system_u:system_r:svirt_lxc_net_t:s0:c556,c641 54440 1 ? S   1:56 /opt/datadog-agent/embedded/bin/python /opt/datadog-agent/agent/agent.py foreground --use-local-forwarder
```

Simply granting the subject context on the target file does not work as it is not for a file object, I suppose. (This is confusing and how I can know which type is for which objects).

```
$ sudo semanage fcontext -a -t svirt_lxc_net_t "/var/run/docker.sock"
ValueError: Type svirt_lxc_net_t is invalid, must be a file or device type
```

### Question

Please help understand:

1. If the cause of permission denied is only due to the SELinux or not.
2. How to find the appropriate context/label to give, and which one to change (process or file).

### Research

There are multiple articles regarding docker and SELinux which tells docker processes inherit svirt (VM) labels and give svirt_sandbox_file_t but it did not work.

```
chcon -R -t svirt_sandbox_file_t /var/run/docker.sock
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue sharing an X unix socket. While sharing regular files with flags `z` or `Z` is possible, it fails with unix sockets. I have discussed it here:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/386767/selinux-and-docker-allow-access-to-x-unix-socket-in-tmp-x11-unix

The best general solution I found was to set docker run option:

```
--security-opt label=type:container_runtime_t
```

Be aware that this probably disables all SELinux protection for this container.

(Though, if you want to share `/var/run/docker.sock` you already give up ***all*** possible protection of the host, not only SELinux. Are you sure you want that?)