# How to interpret sesearch result

Tags: selinux

## Question

Please suggest how to understand sesearch says.

```
$ sesearch -s svirt_lxc_net_t -t container_var_run_t -SA
Found 8 semantic av rules:
   allow svirt_sandbox_domain file_type : dir { getattr search open } ; 
   allow svirt_sandbox_domain pidfile : sock_file { write getattr append open } ; 
   allow svirt_sandbox_domain file_type : filesystem getattr ; 
   allow nsswitch_domain pidfile : dir { getattr search open } ; 
   allow domain pidfile : sock_file { write getattr append open } ; 
   allow svirt_sandbox_domain file_type : file entrypoint ; 
   allow nsswitch_domain pidfile : dir { getattr search open } ; 
   allow nsswitch_domain pidfile : dir { getattr search open } ;
```

### Background

As per [How to find an appropriate SELinux type to prevent “permission denied”](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/178082), trying to find out the cause of "permission denied" due to SELinux.

The process trying to access the object /var/run/docker.sock has svirt_lxc_net_t label and the file has container_var_run_t label. So trying to understand what sesearch says about the relation between svirt_lxc_net_t and container_var_run_t.

https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/SELinux/Tutorials/Controlling_file_contexts_yourself shows a trouble shooting tips and it uses sesearch to show the source has few permissions, but not sure how to interpret.